# Why won't this image hover function bring the elements to the front?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some code to for a gallery of overlapping image elements. I want each image to have a hover event handler that brings that image to the front when the mouse enters the image, and then moves the image back when the mouse leaves the image. As it is now, the images flicker like they are being brought forward then put back straight away. Code available [here](http://alphadesigns.com.au/stackoverflow/gallery/index.html). Any thoughts appreciated, I'm sure this is probably just a css/jq animation fix but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Also, if anyone has an idea on how to improve/optimise that statement that finds out the accumulative width of images in the gallery I'm all ears. I'm sure there has to be a more concise method.

Comment: Got some code we can see?  Need HTML sample, CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For z-index to work properly, you need to make sur that element is positioned relatively.

So, just add position: relative;

```
#jqfg_thumbnails img {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: -50px;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
}
```